# Differentiable but not Absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Please give an example (if it exists) for a function which is differentiable everywhere but not absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$. This is clearly $C^\infty$ but it's not even uniformly continuous. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $x = \sqrt{n\pi}$ and $y = \sqrt{n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}}$. Then (exercise) we can make $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily close by making $n$ large, but $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y) = \pm 1$.

Comment: Can we find such a function defined on closed and bounded interval

Comment: Since every Lipschitz function is absolutely continuous, such a function must have unbounded derivative, so it can't be even $C^1$. I can't think of one off of the top of my head, ask it as a separate question?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ on $[0,1]$. It is differentiable, and, were it absolutely continuous, its derivative would be integrable.

As a consequence, $x \longmapsto \frac{-2}{x}\cos(x^{-2})$ would be integrable over $[0,1]$, thus $x \longmapsto \frac{\cos{x^2}}{x}$ would be integrable over $[1,\infty)$, therefore $u \longmapsto \frac{\cos{u}}{u}$ would be integrable over $(1,\infty)$.

So the function is differentiable yet not absolutely integrable.

Comment: Where did you get $\frac{-2}{x}\sin(x^{-2})$? Don't you have $f'(x)=-\frac{2 \cos \left({x^{-2}}\right)}{x}+2 x \sin ({x^{-2}})$?

Comment: Right. I edited.