# $f(x) \in AC(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f'(x) \notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, absolute-continuity

I have to find some examples of functions $f(x) \in AC(\mathbb{R}) \cap  L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f'(x) \notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

I thought about it but can't find any example. Where can I direct my line of reasoning in order to solve this type of questions?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe $\frac{\sin{e^{x^4}}}{x^2+1}$? The idea is to find a smooth $L^1$ function whose derivative is very much unbounded, so you want it to oscillate very fast.

Comment: @Mindlack but is this function absolutely continuous?

Comment: @Phi_24 If $f$ is continuously differentiable then $f\in AC$.

Comment: @Mindlack You can give a much simpler example, like $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: How do you define $AC(\mathbb R)?$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: @Mindlack https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353473/differentiable-but-not-absolutely-continuous?rq=1